# Changing button action on runtime pushing view controller weirdly

Tags: ios, swift, button, action

My code is so complex so Im gonna minimalize it a little bit.

I have a tableviewController that has 2 cell and a button in view.(Button not in cell).
I'm changing button action according to selected cell :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if indexPath.row == 0{
    self.botButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showA), for: .touchUpInside)
  else{
    self.botButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showB), for: .touchUpInside)

  }
```

> botButton is my button outlet

This is my action buttons :

```
 @objc func showA(){
       let showParcelsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showA") as! showAVC
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(showParcelsViewController, animated: true)
   }



@objc func showB(){
    let decribeland = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showB") as! showBVC
              self.navigationController?.pushViewController(decribeland, animated: true)
}
```

When page load, If I select a row and then tap button , Its perfecly worked.But , For example, If I select 1.row then change to selected row to 2.row and tap button , View pushes First row's
viewcontroller (showAVC) and then pushes Second row's viewcontroller (showBVC) quickly.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems like you add new target on each selection. Try `botButton.removeTarget` for current action before switching another one?

Comment: I did in tableviewDidselect but It didn't seems to me the best solution . Is there any good solution for it

Comment: Sure, there are better solutions to do that depends on your flow, like some answer below. But the problem you specified seems because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target keeps on adding-up as you keep selecting the rows you need to remove the previous target when you add a new one:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        botButton.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showB), for: .touchUpInside)
        botButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showA), for: .touchUpInside)
    } else {
        botButton.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showA), for: .touchUpInside)
        botButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showB), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this. Is it the only solution to solve this issue or Is there any possible solution for it ?

Comment: There are plenty of ways. This is just the tip of the iceberg dude.

Comment: I would recommend using `botButton.tag = indexPath.row` and check the tag in the action to decide which action to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

Set the button `tag` to indexPath.row in `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
   self.botButton.tag = indexPath.row
}
```

Then use the button `tag` to know which controller to present.

```
@IBAction func showBtnPressed(sender : UIButton) { // 
    let index = sender.tag
    if index == 0 {
        let showParcelsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showA") as! showAVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(showParcelsViewController, animated: true)
    } else {
        let decribeland = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showB") as! showBVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(decribeland, animated: true)
    }
}
```